# Anaconda and python qt 5.6 with opengl support

Tags: python, qt, opengl, anaconda

I am having massive issues trying to get my app to use python Qt5.6 in the anaconda environment using python 2.7.

I installed it using the conda package at: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyqt

Listing the anaconda environment shows that I only have qt 5.6 installed as:

```
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py27_0    anaconda
qt                        5.6.0                         1    anaconda
```

Now, I have a simple app as:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
import sys   

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

view = QQuickView()
view.setSource(QUrl("ui/example.qml"))
view.show()
```

The example qml file is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 300; height: 100
    color: "gray"

    Text {
        id: helloworld
        text: "Hello world!"
        color: "blue"
        font.pointSize: 32
    }
}
```

Now, I invoke it I get the following error:

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```